# One among the few shops that offer or offers

Tags: agreement

One among the few shops in London that offer or offers designer clothes.

Comment: @GregLee Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: “[Privileges - comment everywhere](/help/privileges/comment)”, “[Is SE enforcing ‘no answers in comments’?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/is-se-enforcing-no-answers-in-comments)”.

Comment: @Lawrence see above.

Answer (score 1):

One among the few shops in London that offer designer clothes.

"offers" is used when you talk about the singular thing but "shops" is plural so you have to use the offer.

sub+verb+s/es+object.
this is present simple tense and in which you can see Verb should use s/es if Verb is singular.

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: see my edited post

Comment: But the poster's confusion is that he doesn't know what the subject of the verb is — one, or shops. If I were explaining why "offer" is correct I would divide it into the two sentences joined by the conjunction "that", but I'm not going to bother as it has been flagged as a duplicate and will disappear in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to whether you are referring to "one... which offers" or "the few... which offer". From your example, the actual focus of the sentence is somewhat ambiguous. More context would give better clues, for example:

"One among the few shops in London that *offers* designer clothes *is located on Main Street*" if you are referring to a specific shop in this category.

"One among the few shops in London that *offer* designer clothes *may hold the item you're after*" if you are referring to all such shops collectively.